# Yii2 hide filter input action in pretty Url

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2

Hi please help how can i change the url in Yii2 as below, the input values are from form inputs to filter user input value.

```
https://mywebsite/listing/search?select1=Kuala+Lumpur&select2=Private+Room&keyword=Suasana&select3=4&select4=4
```

to

```
https://mywebsite/listing/search/Kuala+Lumpur/Private+Room/Suasana/4/4
```

I tried below code, but it's not working

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'listing/search/<select1>/<select2>/<keyword>/<select3>/<select4>' => 'listing/search',
                'landlord' => 'site/landlord'
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the UrlManager know the patterns that the parameters should match and the ones that they shouldn't.

Looking at the example that you provide:

```
search?select1=Kuala+Lumpur&select2=Private+Room&keyword=Suasana&select3=4&select4=4
```

It seems like you want to match anything to `select1` and `select2`, you could use `.` to match any character and `+` to match one or more occurrences:

```
.+
```

It looks like you only want letters for `keyword`:

```
\w+
```

If you also wanted to match digits:

```
[\w\d]+
```

If you only want to match digits for `select3` and `select4`:

```
\d+
```

Remove the `+` if you only want to match a maximum of one digit.

The UrlManager configuration would look like this:

```php
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'listing/search/<select1:.+>/<select2:.+>/<keyword:\w+>/<select3:\d+>/<select4:\d+>' => 'listing/search',
        'landlord' => 'site/landlord'
    ],
],
```

If you want to experiment with different regex patterns without having to reload the page, I find [regexr](https://regexr.com/) is fantastic.

The [Yii2 docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#named-parameters) themselves have a good section on the topic.

Comment: i tried, but it still not working, i guess it is due to the input values, because the input values were filter from form, i have no idea how to solve it